# Como descobrir a altura de um elemento dinâmico com angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Tenho um menu com efeito accordion eu preciso descobrir qual a altura desse menu, lembrando que a altura é dinâmica, ou seja quando tem algum elemento aberto ele fica maior.

Depois disso é necessario descobrir a posicao do elemento clicado em relação ao scroll.

Basicamente o que eu estou tentando fazer é quando clicado no item reconheço a altura do menu e a posicao dele no scroll,depois subo a tela x% para centralizar o conteúdo clicado.

Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda, obrigado

Comment: A resposta dada esta correta? Resolveu seu problema? Não se esqueça de dar um voto positivo e escolher a resposta correta.

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade o que você precisa é de um componente do angular chamado [**$anchorScroll**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll).

> When called, it scrolls to the element related to the specified hash or (if omitted) to the current value of $location.hash(), according to the rules specified in the HTML5 spec. (Google)

A parte chata desse componente é que você não consegue utilizá-lo em conjunto com o ngAnimate para fazer animações.

Caso você queira fazer com um pouco de animação, você pode dar uma olhada [nesse exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21749878/angular-js-anchorscroll-smooth-duration) do StackOverFlow gringo, que é simples, mas expressa bem o que você quer.